# как считать файл с тхт файла и вывести на экран, сколько раз встречается каждое слово в javascript

Tags: javascript

как считать файл с тхт файла и вывести на экран, сколько раз встречается каждое слово в javascript

```
document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("Filecontents").textContent = this.result;
  }
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0])
})
```

Comment: document.getElementById("openFile").addEventListener('change',function () {
  var  fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("Filecontents").textContent = this.result;
  }
  fr.readAsText(this.files[0])

})

Comment: Под вопросом есть кнопка [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1133080/edit). Отредактируйте ваш вопрос и вставьте код туда.